# Comparison in mysql Trigger for Null Value

Tags: mysql, triggers, nul

This is my trigger after update record.
The `old.ActivatedDate` always is `Null` and `new.ActivatedDate` always is not `Null`.

This is my code, but it is not working because its condition is not returning true to continue other jobs.

```
SET @OldActivateDate := OLD.ActivateDate;
SET @NewActivateDate := NEW.ActivateDate;

IF(@NewActivateDate IS NOT NULL AND @OldActivateDate IS NULL AND @OldActivateDate!=@NewActivateDate)
THEN
/* Do Some Functionality */
END IF;
```

I tested this method also, but again it is not working.

```
if (@NewActivateDate != @OldActivateDate) and ( @NewActivateDate is not null and @OldActivateDate is null )
THEN
/* Do Some Functionality */
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check that `old.ActiveDate` should be `NULL` and `new.ActivateDate` should not be `NULL`, then why do you have other conditions.  Just use:

```
IF (@NewActivateDate IS NOT NULL AND @OldActivateDate IS NULL) THEN
    . . .
END IF
```